# How to change Selected Tab icon using Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have been trying for the last day to do something simple.

I have a Xamarin Forms app.  I need to change the selected tab icon on Android.

I've tried custom renderers, but can't get anything to work.

Does anyone have a recipe or code to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[James M wrote up a solution here](http://motzcod.es/post/157544468267/xamarin-forms-android-selected-and-unselected-tab-colors)

Thak you James M!

Comment: It won't let me click it.  Says I can't for my own answer.

Comment: Sorry didn't know. Here explains why. You will need to wait 48 hrs to be able to do it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: OK, thank you.  It now says I have to wait 7 more minutes.  LOL.  Thanks, Karl